# IRQL Levels: which are high and which are low

Tags: hardware

In IRQL (Interrupt Request Levels) which are the high levels and which are the lower levels?  I'm talking in terms of numbers?

Are the high numbers the high levels or are they the low levels... that's what I'm trying to figure out?

Tony

Comment: what architecture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A higher number is a higher priority.

See [here](http://blogs.technet.com/askperf/archive/2008/01/22/what-is-irql-and-why-is-it-important.aspx) and [here](http://www.osronline.com/ShowThread.cfm?link=127882).